# Laravel : Problem showing image from the storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, image, storage

I'm having a problem viewing image fron the storage folder, here are the codes:

```
->editColumn('image_path', function ($submission) {
                $imgUrl = asset('storage' . str_replace('public', '', $submission->image_path));
                return "<img src=\"{$imgUrl}\" alt=\"Gambar Barang\" width=\"250\" />";
            })
```

I tried ***php artisan storage:link*** it says the link already exists, last time the image was showing but after i deleted my project folder and pasted a new one the images doesn't showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel generate cache version of that storage link..

**Step 1**

Delete the storage folder created by storage link command inside a public folder on your root directory

**Step 2**

Then execute these commands

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

```
php artisan storage:link
```

The output on terminal should be

```
The [public/storage] link has been connected to [storage/app/public].
```